# How to debug redis with memory usage is over 20GB?

Tags: redis

I am having a serious issue with Redis, and I cannot get my head around the root cause of the issue, I am running dockerised redis6-alpine and it is working well in some other setups with the exact configurations, any hint/guidance are appreciated! here is a quick view of my configurations:

```
# Server
redis_version:6.0.14
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:e0ee1c530b6d150b
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.19.0-16-amd64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:10.2.1
process_id:1
run_id:79e32727ad7a6eb2a9427060ba44fa918c01de5a
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:215118
uptime_in_days:2
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:14634210
executable:/data/redis-server
config_file:
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:58
client_recent_max_input_buffer:131072
client_recent_max_output_buffer:786456
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory
used_memory:23814128424
used_memory_human:22.18G
used_memory_rss:25484832768
used_memory_rss_human:23.73G
used_memory_peak:26912783984
used_memory_peak_human:25.06G
used_memory_peak_perc:88.49%
used_memory_overhead:43319344
used_memory_startup:803160
used_memory_dataset:23770809080
used_memory_dataset_perc:99.82%
allocator_allocated:23814697320
allocator_active:25313169408
allocator_resident:25528991744
total_system_memory:135186935808
total_system_memory_human:125.90G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.06
allocator_frag_bytes:1498472088
allocator_rss_ratio:1.01
allocator_rss_bytes:215822336
rss_overhead_ratio:1.00
rss_overhead_bytes:-44158976
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.07
mem_fragmentation_bytes:1670633120
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:1345144
mem_aof_buffer:8
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:193999866
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1625031828
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:0
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:167
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:565936128
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0
aof_current_size:18283706329
aof_base_size:18280419536
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:5857404
total_commands_processed:518486668
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:1821
total_net_input_bytes:177162832735
total_net_output_bytes:8187427886085
instantaneous_input_kbps:432.05
instantaneous_output_kbps:53204.55
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:30957
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:21298
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:372132606
keyspace_misses:10318752
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:593467
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:4
total_reads_processed:394752846
total_writes_processed:382030652
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_replid:2a7e6a090bdaa0474ee666c6c6b555e0c1c3942a
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:12596.074365
used_cpu_user:6090.006186
used_cpu_sys_children:164.531584
used_cpu_user_children:1229.917070

# Modules

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=134616,expires=96904,avg_ttl=777017159
db1:keys=348560,expires=332665,avg_ttl=63989490
```

[redis appendonly.aof file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INONu.png)

Comment: Redis stores the entire database in memory, and `used_memory_dataset:23770809080` says your data set is 22GB large. You'll need to reduce the amount of data you're storing if you want to reduce memory usage.

Comment: @StephenJennings That I understand, I am asking how can we address this kind of problem? how can we filter long/bad dataset sort of speak?